# Glitch free solution to stream sound output from an ubuntu machine to another (14.10 both)

Tags: wireless, sound, pulseaudio, streaming, 14.10

I have this setup: laptop with wifi-AC -> AC capable router -> laptop with AC (directional antenna) -> hi-fi speakers.

I don't have any network problems, everything is really fast and I can play(stream) 1080p video from one laptop to another with smb (Samba & vlc).

The problem is that when I only want to stream the sound output from one laptop with `Pulseaudio`, I get constant and annoying glitches. It is worse when I'm playing a `Youtube` video.

I have Ubuntu 14.10 on both laptops. I have played with `pulseaudio` settings with no success.

Do you have any idea what can I try in order to have a smooth playback over network? 
Maybe some `pulseaudio` settings or another solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stream audio and video with vlc :
f.i. this is a command to stream a video file from your local disk `Video/video.mp4` to a multicast destination on your lan  (copy the command as a single line in a terminal, replacing filename)
`vlc  --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=2000,ab=128,deinterlace}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}' Videos/video.mp4`

On the reading pc(s), run vlc and open the stream `rtp://239.255.12.42`

You can change source file `Video/video.mp4` by a youtube url like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afBm0Dpfj_k`

EDIT: to stream  audio only as played on your first pc,  just change source file `Video/video.mp4` with pulse://
  `vlc  --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=2000,ab=128,deinterlace}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}' pulse://`

Look [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Easy_Streaming_Newer_Versions/) for streaming using vlc interface instead  command line.
Look [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/) for more command line streaming (set stream video size , format etc...)
You can also remotely control the streaming vlc from a web interface on the reading pc: look [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/documentation:modules/http_intf/)

Comment: This would work but it is not as easy as just streaming everything that goes to the sound output. e.g: Now I'm listening to an mp3 and, in the next moment, I want to stop mp3 playback and listen to something on YouTube or another site.

Comment: Edited the answer: if I understand well, you want to stream audio only for listening on your  hifi speaker